# JSF listeners in selectOneMenu

Tags: list, jsf, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu item with some products. Some of them are unavailable so after you click on it the button "Add" should be disabled and some message should appear that "Sorry the product you chose is currently unavailable". I have no idea how to achieve that. Tried listeners, ajax and still nothing.

This is one of many versions of my JSF Page:

```
<h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.productName}">
                <f:selectItems id ="other" value="#{productBean.other}" var="other" itemValue="#{ordersBean.productName}" itemLabel="#{other.name}" />
                <f:ajax listener="#{productBean.valueChanged}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:commandButton value ="Dodaj do zamówienia" rendered="#{productBean.available}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel id="orderSummary"/>
        </h:form>
```

Beans are rather standard. I just need a clue how to do that and probably I will be able to do it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one of the ways:

1. In your AJAX listener you could check if a product is available and set up bean field accordingly, or add a message for a component.
2. Introduce a component in your view that'll hold the message to the user, for example with the `#{bean.available ? '' : 'Sorry, out of stock'}` value, or enclose it within a `<h:panelGroup>` and let that component have a `rendered` attribute, or attach `<h:message>`/`<h:messages>` somewhere in your view.
3. Specify id of the message holder to be rendered within `render` attribute of `<f:ajax>` tag.

Comment: it helped me to succesfully use the ajax listener on selectOneMenu. thank you

Comment: You're welcome! Look at the answer to your follow up question to see more details.